# How to generate line coverage report with vstest.console.exe?

Tags: c#, .net, code-coverage, test-coverage

When I run vstest.console.exe with the parameters, vstest.console.exe App.Tests.dll /collect:"Code Coverage" /Logger:html /EnableCodeCoverage App.dll, it only generates test execution report in the resulting html.

[image]

is it possible to generate line coverage report with this tool also or do I need more tools?
As when I search for line coverage in C#, it takes me to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-code-coverage-to-determine-how-much-code-is-being-tested?view=vs-2019, and this one suggests vstest.console.exe, but it does not generate line coverage.

Comment: Check out coverlet. It can integrate with dotnet test/msbuild test or with Visual Studio directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Overview

[This article](https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/697-qa-measuring-code-coverage) was of great help to me. Nevertheless, I am reproducing the steps here for posterity. I found my solution by using the following tools simulatenously.

- vstest.console.exe (VS.NET 2019 Community edition)
- OpenCover (via NUGET)
- ReporGenerator (via NUGET)

## Background

- I have a simple .NET 48 Web API project
- I have Controller classes and I have written an unit test on these classes

## Add reference to OpenCover NUGET package

I installed the package **opencover** , version 4.7.1221
The package comes along with the command line exe which we will be using for generating coverage information
`C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages\opencover\4.7.1221\tools\OpenCover.console.exe`

## Add reference to ReportGenerator NUGET package

I installed the package **ReportGenerator** , version 5.1.6. The package comes along with the command line exe which we will be using for generating a readable HTML report on the code coverage information produced by the `OpenCover.console.exe` tool
`C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages\reportgenerator\5.1.6\tools\net47\ReportGenerator.exe`

## Running all the tools

### Set the environment variables

```
set VSTEST_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe
set OPENCOVER_PATH=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.nuget\packages\opencover\4.7.1221\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe
set REPORTGEN_PATH=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.nuget\packages\reportgenerator\5.1.6\tools\net47\ReportGenerator.exe


set COVERAGE_RESULTS_FILE=C:\work\code-coverage\mycodecoverage.xml
set COVERAGE_REPORT_DIR=C:\work\code-coverage\myreport
```

### Run the opencover tool to generate code coverage information

```
%OPENCOVER_PATH% -target:"%VSTEST_PATH%" -targetargs:C:\work\WebApp48\WebApplicationGenic\WebApplication1.Tests\bin\Debug\WebApplication1.Tests.dll -filter:"+[WebApplication1]*" -output:%COVERAGE_RESULTS_FILE%
%REPORTGEN_PATH%  -reports:%COVERAGE_RESULTS_FILE% -targetdir:%COVERAGE_REPORT_DIR%
```

### Generate a report using the ReportGenerator tool

```
%REPORTGEN_PATH%  -reports:%COVERAGE_RESULTS_FILE% -targetdir:%COVERAGE_REPORT_DIR%
```

## What are the files that got generated?

- The **OpenCover** will write the coverage information in a XML file(COVERAGE_RESULTS_FILE)
- The **ReportGenerator** tool will consume this XML file and produce a large number of HTML files in the specified output folder (COVERAGE_REPORT_DIR)

## What to expect from the OpenCover tool?

A single large XML file - which I cannot make much sense of!
[image]

## What to expect from the Report Generator tool?

### HTML files

[image]

### Index.html

We can locate our Controller classes.
[image]

### Detailed coverage information

Click on `ValuesController` line item in the **index.html** to see the detailed coverage information. We can see the lines of code that are not being tested.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Test Coverage is only supported in Enterprise license of Visual Studio.
There are some 3-rd party tools you can use:

1. dotCover - paid. Part of ReSharper suite
2. openCover - open source.